# Can't install application on iPhone

Tags: iphone, bundle, identifier

When I try to install on iPhone I get the following:

**Can't install application**

**The Info.plist for application at (null) specifies a CFBundleExecutable of (null), which do not exist**

The Bundle identifier matches the one on file at Apple and the phone has the provisional certificate...

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did You try to clean before building your app ?

Are You sure that all Your certificates are in order ?

Comment: Yes,,, I did find the answer here  http://brainwashinc.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/the-info-plist-for-application-at-null-specifies-a-cfbundleexecutable-of-null-which-does-not-exist/#comment-126

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CFBundleExecutable represents the **Product Name** property in your configuration.  Here's the first hit on Google for the solution... [google result](http://www.verysimple.com/blog/2009/03/22/the-infoplist-for-application-at-null-specifies-a-cfbundleexecutable-of-null/)

Quoting

> When debugging an iPhone app on the device you may get the error “The Info.plist for application at (null) specifies a CFBundleExecutable of (null), which does not exist”
>
> This can happen if you have dashes in
>   your “product name,” or if the
>   “product name” doesn’t match in your
>   main project info, target info and
>   possibly the name of your target.  The
>   compiler seems to use dashes as a
>   delimiter in the link map and so it
>   causes null errors.

Comment: I found the answer... it is at http://brainwashinc.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/the-info-plist-for-application-at-null-specifies-a-cfbundleexecutable-of-null-which-does-not-exist/#comment-126

Answer (score 0):

The "The Info.plist for application at (null)" suggest that Xcode cannot locate the Info.plist file in the app bundle.

In the finder, check the build directory for the built app and open the application package to find Info.plist. If it is not present or if is is misconfigured, that is the problem. If not check for permissions problems (very rare).

Comment: I found the answer here.. http://brainwashinc.wordpress.com/2009/11/02/the-info-plist-for-application-at-null-specifies-a-cfbundleexecutable-of-null-which-does-not-exist/#comment-126

Thanks